# openMp: need to parallelize a loop having data dependency problem

Tags: c, openmp

I wanted to know whether there is a way to parallelize a **"for loop"** having data dependency problem using **OpenMP**.

here is the **for loop** which I like to parallelize

```
int k = 0;
int A[100][100];
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
           A[i][j] = k;
           k++;
    }
}
```

Do anyone have a solution for this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't *really* have a data dependency problem there, because `k` can be computed from `i` and `j`:

```
int A[100][100];
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        A[i][j] = i * 100 + j;
    }
}
```

If you can give a more realistic example of what you're trying to do, we may be able to help you more.

Comment: nice case of having to undo the speedups that were done for a single threaded case, so that the code can be parallelized.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, at first glance, is that `k` is not being declared as a derived value; it is a value external to the loop, which could be confusing the compiler.

You could rewrite your loop to explicitly specify `k` as a function of `i` and `j`, and retain the same behaviour:

```
int A[100][100];
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
           const int k = i * 100 + j;
           A[i][j] = k;
    }
}
```